# adding custom LISTBOX on dockframe window

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to add a custom (static) list box which i created using toolbox on a fromview i need to add this listbox on the Dockpaneview (Output window) provided by MFC.
How to add the custom list box on the output window

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add list box at output window by using Panel control.[image]

then you can what are the controls you need to display on output window.
For example:

To add text box and button;
[image]

[image]

I hope you will done.